# Search any content from div tag and show the searched div at top of all divs

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <div class="search-container">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Search</button>
    </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
            <img src="~/ProfileImg/30052018051539_crop.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <p><strong><a onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" ></a></strong></p><p class="custom_j"><strong><a>Dr. Amruta Kadam</a></strong></p><p></p>
            <p>MD (HOMEOPATHY)</p>
            <p>Dermatologist</p>
            <div class="info">
                Chaitanya clinic, Shankar complex
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <dt>
                        <div class="Strong">Distance</div>
                    </dt>
                    <div class="desc"><span>10km</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <dt>
                        <div class="Strong">Reviews</div>
                    </dt>
                    <div class="desc"><span>0</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="row ">
                        <h5>Insurance<span style="color: rgb(0, 186, 242);"> Partners</span></h5>
                        <div class="popup-gallery">
                            <a href="#" title="Photo 1">
                                <img src="/Loginassets/images/lic.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" title="Photo 1">
                                <img src="/Loginassets/images/india.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" title="Photo 1">
                                <img src="/Loginassets/images/more.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wants to search a content from a div tag from a list of div as above, I currently given only one div. I wants to search a text and the matching text div will display at top of all divs.
I wants a search result like jquery datatable search result. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: add js code you tried

Comment: $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('div.col-sm-6 col-md-8').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
             $this.closest('div.col-sm-6 col-md-8').fadeOut();
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code: search with "HOMEOPATHY" or "1111" etc, it will hide another row

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/WyQzwZ

You have passed wrong class name. I have taken new class name and it is working.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){ 
    var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase(); console.log(query)
    $('div.test').each(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this); if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1) 
            $this.closest('div.test').fadeOut(); 
        }); 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much mam you save my time